# Perforce to Mercurial Import

Tags: mercurial, perforce, kiln

I'm trying to move over some repositories from Perforce to Kiln (FogBugz's Mercurial-based companion VCS), and I'm having some issues.

As Kiln does not port directly from Perforce, I'm going via the Perforce -> Mercurial -> Kiln approach, but I'm having some difficulties with the PF to Mercurial convert.

I'm running

```
hg convert //depot/... kiln-hg
```

but it's crashing randomly while importing the changelist, always at ~#4030.
 One a couple of occasions it gets to the end of the changelist, at which point it goes:

```
3751 change file structure
```

and just stops (or so it seems).

Does anyone have *any* idea why this might be?

Cheers, Ed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why convert isn't helping (but make sure you're using the very latest mercurial), but you might try using the [perfarce extension](http://www.kingswood-consulting.co.uk/hg/perfarce/).  After doing that you could, perhaps, clone the resulting repo.

Comment: Downloaded Merc yesterday so should be OK on that front. I thought the Perfarce extension was for using hg or tortoiseHG with perforce?

Comment: Could be.  I just know that it sees more active development than does the convert extension, so it might be more current.

Comment: perfarce doesn't improt the history (which is a shame). Turned out I just had to run the import on a 32bit machine (for some reason).